# Knowing when the Clear button is pressed

Tags: android, button, notifications

Is it possible (i'm sure it is because i've seen other apps do it) to know when the clear notifications button is pressed without having an active notification?

For instance, I need to know if the user has an SMS notification, if he pushes clear I would like to be told. Is there a callback for this?

Comment: Previously asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956774/does-android-provide-a-callback-when-the-clear-button-on-notifications-list-is-cl)

Comment: Right, I saw that post. But the way I understand, that will only trigger if you have a notification in the list. I need to check for other apps notificiations

Comment: @Bwoogie - I know this isn't relatvent to your question, but why? What could you possibly want to do (or even care if) the user clears all notifications?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible (i'm sure it is because i've seen other apps do it) to know when the clear notifications button is pressed without having an active notification?

No, it is not possible.

> I need to know if the user has an SMS notification

No, you do not. For starters, there are a few hundred SMS clients, many of which will use `Notifications`, so there is no singular "SMS notification". And, as noted, you do not have any means of determining when other applications add or remove `Notifications`.